# Sound played when database is updated

Tags: php, audio

I am working on a leader-board; I need a sound to be played (automatically) when the values on the leader-board are changed through the CMS.

Any ideas, links, suggestions are very welcome.

Using PHP / MySQL

Thank you.

Comment: A sound on serverside or on clientside ?

Comment: Client side... I guess, there will be an screen showing the leader board, and there is the sound needed to call the attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play the sound without reloading the page, i think you have to use AJAX. Otherwise you have to check, on reload, with PHP if anything changed. After that you should use javascript to play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the  or  html tags can help you out here? Of course you need some wiring (with PHP or Javascript maybe) to do, to get it working on the moment you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript to play a sound. Because a browser is clientside the server cannot communicate with a browser to alert it when something has changed.

Basically you should set up some recurring checks in your code that verify if something has changed. If some values did change, you can update your webpage and play a sound by making use of Javascript.

A tutorial about how to play sounds can be found [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/sound/play.htm).